Sound card is undetected or driver is not installed on ubuntu 24.04
I don't have sound anymore since my upgrade to 24.04
lscpi gives:
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 11)
but aplay -l gives:
aplay: device_list:277: aucune carte son n'a été trouvée...
(no soundcard detected).
My only output is named "dummy output" and I can't manage to have sound on my computer.
Is there any solution to that trouble?
Thanks

Did sound work before upgrading to 24.04? Can you please load 24.04 from a live USB and check if the sound works there? Then we can try to fix potential problems with the upgrade

If sudo aplay -l sees the sound card, you have a group membership issue. Please [edit] your Question and show us ls -l /dev/<your device name> and id. Do not reply via Add Comment.
